# Chinese equivalent of "a bad apple spoils the barrel"

Tags: translation

What is the Chinese equivalent of the English idiom "**a bad apple spoils the barrel**"?

Comment: try web search with "翻译：  a bad apple spoils the barrel"  ->  http://www.ichacha.net/zaoju/bad%20apple.html        One bad apple can spoil the whole barrel    一个烂苹果坏了一桶苹果。  One " bad apple " spoils the whole office
一个坏员工带坏整个办公室

Comment: also enter "one bad" into jukuu: 2.  One bad boy may infect a whole class.
 一个坏学生可能会影响全班。 16.  One bad deed can blemish a good reputation.
 一次不良的行为可损害好的名声。

Comment: jukuu:  One corrupt apple corrupts many sound ones.
 一个烂苹果可以使许多好苹果腐烂。 Regarding below answers note:
imperfect analogy: 老鼠屎 seems to be a foreign substance introduced in food item, unlike bad apple among other good apples, 比拟有缺点:老鼠屎好象是放在某种食物里的外来物质，和好苹果中的坏苹果是不一样的

Comment: **answer is in jukuu!**  enter "rotten apple": 1.  Scott： It just goes to show that one rotten apple spoils the barrel. Now we all have to carry a pass and sign in every evening.
 史考特：这证明了一粒老鼠屎，坏了一锅粥。现在我们每晚都必须带通行证还要签到。

Answer (score 6):

Chinese has an idiom: 害群之马, it refers to the *bad apple* which spoils the barrel. Literally, it says : a horse that brings trouble to its herd.

“a bad apple spoils the barrel” also has a Chinese counterpart: 一个老鼠屎坏了一锅汤, but it is kinds of rude, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

[一粒老鼠屎壞了一鍋粥](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E7%B2%92%E8%80%81%E9%BC%A0%E5%B1%8E%EF%BC%8C%E5%A3%9E%E4%BA%86%E4%B8%80%E9%8D%8B%E7%B2%A5)

one grain of rat feces ruins the whole pot of porridge